# Positioning system for skips

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, transportation

We need to position skips to within a few (~10?) cm on level ground. I've seen positioning systems for roll on/off containers, these were horizontal guide rails on the ground and presumably the container is pushed between them.

Skips are lowered onto the ground from above:
[image]
*Source: [Loacker](http://images.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&source=imgres&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwin7ZO6yIvMAhUFzRQKHfCADsMQ5RMIBDAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.loacker.cc%2Fhu%2Fstoffstroeme%2Fdienstleistungen%2Fcontainersysteme%2Fabsetzcontainer.html&usg=AFQjCNHCG5Bi92__niOkHFGNHsHdiBPM4w)*

At first glance, a few bars jutting from the ground at an angle (to form a funnel) could do the trick. From looking at videos the skips swing when beeing set down. The bars would need a coating with PE or a similar soft(er than metal) and tough material.

I don't want to invent something as I'm sure this is a solved problem. So far my googling hasn't brought me to a solution. What to do when your skip needs exact placements?

Comment: I've tagged this as civil engineering because this is probalby common in waste and sludge handling and this is often the domain of CEs. If you have better ideas for tagging, go for it!

Comment: I removed your product sourcing request. Rules here are that people can volunteer products, but you can not directly ask for them.

Comment: Not relevant to the question itself, but why do you need such precision (if you can call it that) for skips?

Comment: BEcause they will be filled automatically by conveyors and they need to be where the copnveyor drops material ....

Answer (score 2):

I could not find anything in an internet search either.

A steel wedges like you show should work fine. The taller the wedges the easier it will be for the driver to position. The swinging will stop when the dumpster strikes the wedges; perhaps they will need additional anchoring or tied together to repeatedly handle this.

Polyethylene like you mentioned, would help protect the paint and consequential corrosion. Polyethylene tubing (pex) sliced and slid over steel bar that forms the wedge shape would be an economical solution.

Pressure treated wood, crude as it may seem, may also be a viable solution because it will be easier on the dumpster and absorbs impact energy. Anchored sand bags could also be used. They would have to occasionally be replaced, but would offer very good dampening of the swinging motion.

If you have control over the positioning equipment you could install dampening on the chains so that swinging is not an issue. Something like this [door dampener](https://www.zoro.com/norton-door-closers-hydraulic-door-closer-8301/i/G0035603/) attached to one of the chains on either side (for symmetry) would quickly slow any swinging.